# iOS: Problem with horizontal centers alignment and layout

Tags: swift, autolayout, xcode10

I want the below Yes and No buttons to be at bottom center of the screen side-by-side, always with same width. The other labels are behaving as expected. Problem is with the buttons. They just appear with skewed size with different widths, not centered to the bottom of the UIView.

I tried many ways - aligned all the elements centrally horizontal etc.
Also I embedded these button in a UIView and aligned the header label, description label and this UIView centrally. Did not work.

I did not try code as I was trying in Xcode Storyboards.

Here is how I want...
[image]

Comment: The correct way is to embed the two buttons into a `UIView` as you tried. 
Then set the buttons constraints relatively to the `UIView` they're nested in ( like 10px-YES-20px-NO-10px and YES.width == NO.Width ). Then you center the `UIVIew` horizontaly in superView. From there you can either give a fixed width to the `UIView`, one of the two `UIButton`, or either make the UIView width equal to 50% of its superView width, for instance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56386677/how-to-use-frame-to-set-x-position-in-loop-on-swift As my answer shows, a UIStackView just does this automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by that steps:
1. Embed buttons into a view
2. Add a width constrain between buttons.
3. Add left, top, bottom insets to the YES button.
4. Add right, top, bottom insets to the NO button.
5. Add constraint to equal width of the YES and NO buttons.
6. Add bottom inset constraint for the view.
7. Add add center horizontally constraint to the view.
8. If buttons have less width when you need, add width constraint to the YES button.

[image: Screenshot of constraints for the buttons]

[image: Screenshot of constraints for the view]

Comment: Thank you. I missed giving the spacing between description label buttons UIView.That solved the problem.